# Show "Open in Background" Menu with a Long Press?

Tags: iphone, safari

On older iOS devices, if you pressed and held a link in Safari, it would pop up a menu with options like "Copy Link," "Open in Background," etc. On my current phone, doing this causes a preview window to open up and only shows these options if I swipe upward.

I'm not a huge fan of this new system - it doesn't let me see what the URL of the link I'm clicking is and it makes it harder to open a ton of links for later perusal.

Is there any way to disable this preview window and just show the menu of options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This new menu is "Peek and Pop," which is activated by 3D touch. It works by measuring how much pressure you put on the screen when you touch it.

You can disable it or change the sensitivity in Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch:

[image: 3D touch settings menu]

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205056

Answer (score 2):

I am on a iPhone 6s with iOS 10.3.3 and Safari still works that way.

What you describe is the behavior when you 3D (force) touch the link: you get a "peek" of the destination site (and if you press more you get a "pop", committing to following the link).
Try just "touching" the link (and keeping your finger on it) and to wait for a second, the menu should appear.
 
In any case you can adjust the 3D touch sensibility (or disable it) in the Settings:
General ! Accessibility | 3D Touch

Comment: The magic words were "3D Touch," and that disabled it. Thanks so much!

Comment: But you also put the screenshott and the reference to the support page.